# 2.9x How do I calibrate my colors for shaders and UV maps?

Tags: lighting

I don't know how to set up a scene to test my colors. I would like to know a procedure to set up the scene for this test. I tried using different methods but my character was still too dark even when everything else seemed correct.

How should I set up my scene to calibrate my colors and UV shaders properly?

Blender v2.79 has a histogram to verify an image but does it exist in 2.9x versions of Blender? 
 [ EDIT ] Answer: @susu The histogram and waveform monitor are available in the image editor [i.stack.imgur.com/dRf9u.jpg.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRf9u.jpg.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: The histogram and waveform monitor are available in the image editor https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRf9u.jpg. Can you add more detail on how you are using the color checker? What chart are you using, and where did you get it from and what color space is it on?

Comment: @susu I didn't use it with Blender but other 3D software. I just seen other artists use it and hoped it would help me calibrate my colors. I image Googled "x-rite" I never used it other than adding it to a scene and see if it wasn't blown out or too dark. I don't know what color space I am using with Blender.

Comment: Do a bit more research on how to use it. There is no "universal" colorchecker, let alone a picture downloaded from a random place... Take a look at https://github.com/colour-science/colour-nuke/tree/master/colour_nuke/resources/images/ColorChecker2014 you must know what the colorspace is and how it is converted to the display referred image at the end. Keep in mind that the final color depends on the color transforms set in the color management section.

Comment: @susu No! Never assume the user "must know" anything besides being able to read english. I know what "Color Management" is, it's a section in the Scene tab that say sRGB and Filmic etc. If you use jargon you will never teach anything to those who are new to this thing you call colorspace. Also, what am I supposed to do with these EXR files? I am no further ahead.

Comment: I think what they mean is due to how color information is distorted in compressed images files (.jpg for instance), and due to the inner mechanics in each software to make the color "look good" to the human eye (colorspace), and also the hardware (your screen, your graphics card), you should be careful when calibrating your colors. EXR files are color files, like jpg, but they are uncompressed, and can contain multiple layers of data. The link shows that, to be truly precise, you have to match the right file with the color transform you are using, since there are so many different combinations